# Spree install not working. Getting error: undefined method `add_module' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, spree

I am following basic instructions mentioned here: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

BTW I already have `gem 'devise-encryptable'` in my Gemfile.

when I `cd` into `mystore` and try to run `spree install`, this is the error I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-encryptable-0.1.1/lib/devise/encryptable/encryptable.rb:28:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `add_module' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-encryptable-0.1.1/lib/devise-encryptable.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-encryptable-0.1.1/lib/devise-encryptable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/mystore/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

what is happening and how do I fix it? I happen to be using the latest version of both rails and spree. the devise version I have installed is `devise-2.2.2`

UPDATE: here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem 'pg'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise-encryptable'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'spree', '1.3.1'
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '1-3-stable'
```

Comment: Please show us your entire `Gemfile`.

Comment: @RyanBigg Have updated question with my Gemfile

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try placing this line
`gem 'devise-encryptable'`

in the bottom of the Gemfile. This fixed the problem for me. Probably the devise-encryptable gem finds the old version of Devise which does not have the Devise.add_module method.

Comment: Thank you George. Can't believe I wasted hours of my time for this

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error just now and have a solution. You need to open file `lib/devise-encryptable.rb` in the gem's directory and add this line at the beginning: `require 'devise'`. And don't forget to follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486614/2008610). Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `gem 'devise-encryptable'` from your Gemfile, as it is already specified as a dependency in the `spree_auth_devise` gem. What's happening here is that this gem is being loaded before the `devise` gem, which is why your application is breaking.

Comment: This did not work but moving the line to the bottom of the file did.